# request for any expository works in pointwise convergence of double Fourier series and especially a paper by Hardy

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Quart. J. Math. Volume 37, Issue 1, Pages 53-79
On double Fourier series, and especially those which represent the double zeta-function with real and incommensurable parameters.
Hardy, G.H.

I am not able to find this old paper anywhere on the internet. Could someone point me to any copy of it or any other exposition work that kind of repreoduces/explains this work?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right reference? [Volume 37 of 4JM is published in 1986](http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/37/1.toc) Hardy passed away considerably earlier than that. // I also checked the volume published in 1937, and the paper you referred to is not there.

Comment: Ah, you meant [this Quarterly Journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quarterly_Journal_of_Pure_and_Applied_Mathematics). Volume 37 is 1906; unfortunately GDZ only has up to volume 31, and the internet archive has volumes [35](https://archive.org/details/quarterlyjourna02glaigoog) and [39](https://archive.org/details/quarterlyjourna49unkngoog) but not 37. I know you are on Google+, so maybe you should post to #ArticleRequest ?